# How risky is it to let someone know the name of your Windows PC?

Tags: network, windows, attacks, ip, windows-10

I have here a situation where if I share this file with someone on the internet, the file may contain: 1. data pointing to the directories where it is stored on my computer, along with 2. the name of the computer (the “Device Name” under “About your PC” in Windows), which the person receiving the file may be able to extract. If this does fall into the hands of someone with malicious intent, what can they do with this information? Would they be able to try and get into this PC remotely?

If 1 and 2 would not be enough information, hypothetically would it be possible if they had already obtained 3. the IP address of that computer as well?

Comment: What do u mean by share? Do u have like an online share directory? Like http, ftp or so ?

Comment: @Dreamer64 email attachment, google drive and stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of those informations are considered to be secrets, and cannot be directly used to access your machine. And if you are speaking about a home machine, it is normally *hidden* behind your ISP router and its IP address cannot be used from the outside world. Only the external address of your box (modem + router) can be used from the outside.

That being said, they are still *personal* informations that could be used to better know about you, mainly if they are merged with other traces you could have left on social networks. Those informations are mainly used to send you *targetted advertisements*, but can also be used to try and guess your passwords or answers to the frowned upon secret questions that some site use to allow you to recover a forgotten password.

Long story made short, it is the usual balance between security and useability. There is no mean to be paranoiac, but we should avoid to give too much information without a good reason. Like in the real world, you avoid to leave your home without first locking the door, but you probably not hire armed guards to protect it.